# Limit of matrix function

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, limits, convergence-divergence, matrix-calculus

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a matrix whose real eigenvalues have negative real part, and $X=X^\top\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a positive semidefinite matrix, i.e., $X\succeq 0$. Consider the following matrix-valued function 
$$\tag{1}\label{1}
F(X) = \left(\int_0^{\infty} e^{At} X e^{A^\top t} \mathrm{d} t\right)^{-1/2} X \left(\int_0^{\infty} e^{At} X e^{A^\top t} \mathrm{d} t\right)^{-1/2}
$$
which maps positive (semi)definite matrices into a positive (semi)definite matrices. (Here $\cdot^{1/2}$ denotes the symmetric square root of a positive semidefinite matrix and $e^{\cdot}$ is the matrix exponential).

Note that \eqref{1} is a continuous function which is not defined for any $X\succeq 0$ such that $\int_0^{\infty} e^{At} X e^{A^\top t} \mathrm{d} t$ is singular. However, I wonder whether it is possible to define a continuous extension of $F(\cdot)$ in the set of positive semidefinite matrices.

> In more formal terms, let $\bar{X}\succeq 0$ be such that $\int_0^{\infty} e^{At} \bar{X} e^{A^\top t} \mathrm{d} t$ is singular, and let $\{X_n\}_{n\ge 0}$, $X_n\succ 0$, be any sequence such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} X_n = \bar{X}$. Does $
> \lim_{n\to \infty} F(X_n)$ exist and is finite?

My question is motivated by the special case of scalar matrices $A=\alpha I$, $\alpha<0$, for which it is easy to see that the above limit exists and is finite. For general $A$'s, however, it is not clear to me whether this limit still exists. Numerical simulations suggest that the answer is again in the affirmative, but I was not able to prove it.

Comment: Whenever it's defined, the function $g(Q) = \int_0^\infty e^{At}Qe^{A^T}t$ takes input $Q$ and produces a solution $X = g(Q)$ to the [continuous Lyapunov equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation)
$$
AX + XA^T + Q = 0
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Right, thanks! However, I do not see how this can be helpful.

Comment: Whenever the inverse of this $X$ is defined, $Y = X^{-1}$ satisfies the equation 
$$
YA + A^TY + YQY = 0
$$

Comment: I'm not quite sure if that helps either

Comment: I don't follow. Isn't the boxed statement obviously false in some cases? E.g. consider the case where $A=-I_2,\ \bar{X}=0$ and $X_n=diag(\frac1n,0)$.

Comment: @user1551: Sorry there was a typo: the sequence $\{X_n\}_{n\ge 0}$ is composed by positive definite matrices.

Comment: In some case transformations of the form $X \mapsto \rho^{-1/2} X \rho^{-1/2}$ which are not defined when $\rho$ is singular, are considered in the support of $\rho$. I beilieve this is essentially the same as using the Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse.